# How to use a variable value as the key name in an ajax data submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit some data via Ajax, but one of my key names and its value must be dynamic. This is what I mean:

```
var ProductName = $('#Product').attr('name'); // #Product is hidden form element
var ProductID = $('#Product').val();
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'form/processor/page',
            data: {
                SomeElement: ItsValue,
                AnotherElement: ItsValue,
                ProductName: ProductID // this one must be dynamic
            },
    ....
```

So essentially I want to use the value of the `ProductName` variable to provide the key name, and `ProductID` to provide the key's value.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var data = { 
    SomeElement: ItsValue,
    AnotherElement: ItsValue
};
data[ProductName] = ProductID;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'form/processor/page',
    data: data,
    ...
});
```

Comment: how do I pass this along with the existing  data I have `SomeElement: ItsValue,
                AnotherElement: ItsValue`,

Answer (score 3):

Create a data variable and assign the key value pairs

```
var post_data = {}
data[$('#Product').attr('name')] = $('#Product').val()
data["not_dynamic_key"] = "not dynamic value"

$.ajax({
   data : post_data ...
```

Comment: but how do I include the other elements that are not dynamic alongside this? the `SomeElement: ItsValue,
                AnotherElement: ItsValue`